# Style differences of input type text and number

Tags: html, css, input, sass

I've got this code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wscInputHelpComponent">
    <div class="cInputWithButton">
        <input class="cInputAddon" type="text">
        <div class="cInputButton"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS (SCSS):**

```
.wscInputHelpComponent {
    .cInputWithButton {
        display: flex;
        height: 25px;
        .cInputAddon {
            width: 50px;
            height: 100%;
            border-right: none;
        }
        .cInputButton {
            width: 25px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: $APP_COLOR;
            &:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
                background-color: $APP_COLOR_LIGHT;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When my input has `type="text"` I got this result:

[image]

When I change it to `type="number"`:

```
<div class="wscInputHelpComponent">
    <div class="cInputWithButton">
        <input class="cInputAddon" type="number">
        <div class="cInputButton"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I got this result:

[image]

When I use `type="number"` for my input, it moves my div 1-2px to the top, but why, what's the difference and why doesn't it work for each type of "text" and "number"?

**EDIT:**

I've found this the global style:

```
input[type="number"] {margin-top: 3px;}
```

I removed it, now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is default padding on `<input>` element. Try this:

```
.cInputAddon {
  ...
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0423d8p8/)**

```css
.wscInputHelpComponent .cInputWithButton {
  display: flex;
  height: 25px;
}
.wscInputHelpComponent .cInputWithButton .cInputAddon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-right: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wscInputHelpComponent .cInputWithButton .cInputButton {
  width: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.wscInputHelpComponent .cInputWithButton .cInputButton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wscInputHelpComponent">
  <div class="cInputWithButton">
    <input class="cInputAddon" type="number">
    <div class="cInputButton"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="wscInputHelpComponent">
  <div class="cInputWithButton">
    <input class="cInputAddon" type="text">
    <div class="cInputButton"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually cannot reproduce the issue. But mind the text box border.

```css
    .cInputWithButton {
      display: flex;
      height: 25px;
    }
    .cInputWithButton > .cInputAddon {
      width: 50px;
      height: calc(100% - 2px); 
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      border-right: none;
    }
    .cInputWithButton > .cInputButton {
      width: 25px;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid red;
      background-color: red;
      display: inline;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wscInputHelpComponent">
  <div class="cInputWithButton">
    <input class="cInputAddon" type="number">

    <div class="cInputButton"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've found it.. I found in a global-css-file follow style: input [type="number"]{margin-top: 3px;} - so it added this also in my input here...I removed it now it works. But thanks..